# Where is the 'mid-position' of a sentence?

Tags: adverb-position, adjuncts

This question may sound simple, but I have never actually seen anyone define it. Where is the mid-position in a sentence? Is it between the subject and the predicate (everything other than the subject, for those who consult a different grammar from me)?

Take these examples:

> [1] Jake, **walking his dog**, enjoyed a leisurely stroll through the park.
>
> [2] The man, **confident and narcissistic**, faced the crowd without a care.
>
> [3] He **quickly** ran down the corridor.

These bold elements are in mid-position — nobody would dispute that — but I'm wondering if there are any other constructions that break this rule and aren't placed at the end or beginning.

For example, a conjunctive adverb:

> [4] He was, **however**, the greatest doctor in the village.
>
> [5] He, **however**, was the greatest doctor in the village.

These are considered 'clause adjuncts', so I imagine that there's a different set of rules concerning them.

Comment: It's loosely defined, and usually as woolly as 'neither initial nor terminal' as if sentences never had more than 3 slots. Parentheticals only have one comma, dash etc if in sentence-initial or terminal position. // [3b] He quickly ran down the corridor. / [3c] He ran quickly down the corridor. ([3a] and [3d] have the adverb in sentence-initial (with a comma) and terminal positions respectively.)

Comment: I don't understand. What is the rule that they break? Where is the term "mid position" used?

Comment: @JohnLawler Typically, when people describe the places in which an element such as an adverb or a participle clause can be placed, they use terminology like 'front', 'end', and 'mid'. The initial two are obvious, but the latter isn't. I say 'rule' because you can't place these elements anywhere.

Comment: Really? That's too bad, because there is much more precise terminology available; I wouldn't listen to grammatical advice from people who know so little about grammar. In fact the most common position for most adverbs is following the first auxiliary verb, or immediately before the main verb if there are no auxiliaries. But usually there are.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As usual, resources online love to make up their own meaningless terms. It seems that this is just another example. Cheers. Edit: By resources online, I don't mean you, just in case the direction in which my comment was aimed isn't clear.

Comment: @JohnLawler These are the same people who use terms like 'noun clause', so though they would love to think that they have a solid grasp on grammar, they are presenting oversimplified explanations that fall down upon further examination. I would know, as I have asked many questions on this forum under the assumption of existing knowledge learned from similar resources.

Comment: In a teaching/learning context, mid-position can make sense (and the link shows the def, coheres with what John Lawler said above. I don't think I'd argue with the people from the Cambridge Dictionary who use it for that purpose along with front and end: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position That said, it's obviously not suited to drilled-down or technical  discussions about grammar by linguists. So, the question here is: Who is saying this and to whom are they saying it?

Comment: @Lambie I realise that I haven't given much context to this. I have seen this term on multiple occasions while looking through different articles. This came to mind recently because I was researching non-essential participle clauses with explicit subjects (absolute constructions) and where they are positioned. They are most commonly placed at the beginning or end of a clause; however, they can also appear in the middle. I wanted to know the rules, but all I could find was a general statement about their position in the middle, so I turned to here.

Comment: Well, middle is relative. Participle clauses have to be next to what they modify. That's the "rule". Because if they are not next to the noun they modify (before or after), it can create a dangling modify.

Comment: I haven't come across the term mid-sentence (as a formal term), but in composition there are periodic, loose and "mid-branching" sentences. In a mid-branching sentence, the beginning of the main clause is separated by x (whatever the writer can dream up) from its end or conclusion. In this case "mid," is a variable, as I suspect of mid-sentence as it applies to the positioning of absolute constructions. 

 40 mins ago